# If $G/H$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ then $H$ is normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group and $H$ be a closed subgroup such that $G/H$ is homeomorphic (as a manifold) to the abelian group $\mathbb R^n$.

Then, is it necessary that $H$ has to be normal subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Do you have any ideas? Unfortunately, your question sounds like a request for someone to answer a homework problem.

Comment: I mean I know that  if $G/H$ has a group structure inherited from the structure on $G$ then $H$ has to be normal. But my question what if the structure on $G/H$ is inherited from another space?

Comment: Off the top of my head (not sure if this is a correct answer) what if you let $G$ be the group of affine linear automorphisms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $H$ be the subgroup of linear transformations i.e. $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$?  Then $G / H$ in one of the directions should be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ by taking the image of 0, but $H$ wouldn't be normal.

Comment: Try not to just post questions, as people won't know where to start to be able to help you (and you will get downvotes and close votes, as happened here). Try to explain what you have tried and where and why you got stuck/need help. It would also help if you said where you found this question (week X of course Y, where we covered topic Z).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,take $G=\pmatrix{a&b\cr 0&c}, a,c>0 0$, $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$, consider the subgroup $H=\pmatrix{a&0\cr 0&c}$ of $G$, $G/H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, but $H$ is not normal in $G$.

Comment: $H$ is not normal in $G$ @Monsour

Answer (score 0):

Let $G=$ the matrices in $GL_2(\Bbb{R})$ with positive determinant and let $H$ be the diagonal matrices in $G$.  Then $H$ is a closed subgroup that is not normal, and $G/H$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^2$.